# Changing ODI WORKREP Type after being created

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

i did an ODI installation for a development environment. i did one mistake when i chose the workrep type to E which is execution mode.
is there any way to modify this type to development D after it is being created?

please help as i have to change 9 installations!

Regards and Thanks,
Wissam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible as it didn't create all the tables used by a development-type repository.

You can run the RCU (Repository Creation Utility) to drop these environments and then run it again to re-created it with the proper type.

Execution type repository is recommended for any environment where no development is supposed to be done. That way, developers are forced to work on the proper environment (Dev) and the lifecycle is clean.